# [ruby]Create an application

Tags: ruby, exe

I saw on the web that we can create any files, applications who run on the pc and so ruby doesn't limit only at the web.

I would like however check my impression, can we develop any applications for example in .exe with ruby ?

And if the answer is yes, how create an application (with or within framework) and are there any tutorials ?

Thank you in advance for your futures answers and if you have any questions, don't hesitate ! ;)

Comment: Did you try to google your questions? You should find plenty of information and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to create an executable containing Ruby Code:
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables

Even with a GUI:
https://github.com/Shoes3/shoes3

But it depends what you want to achieve. The possibilities are very limited using pure Ruby. Using Html/JS with cross-platform frameworks will be more likely to compete with native applications.

Comment: I would not support the "very limited" part. It also really depends on the operating system you use and the amount and kind of user input you need.